# Send variables in the page URL of an iframe

Tags: php

I didn't found any answer about this on French forums (yes I am French). 
So I will be glad if someone could help me here to fix this issue.

I have a website on which users can login, they login through my website but the authentication is made on an external website that I add in my website using an iframe.

Actually, the code works fine, except for IE8 where the authentication doesn't work.

Here is the code

--> Form :

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<input name="username" type="text">
<input name="password" type="text">`<input type="submit" value="OK" name="validation">
</form>
```

--> and here is the login.php page

```
  <?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
?>
<iframe src="http://myurl.com/verify.php?username=<?php echo "$username"; ?>&password=<?php echo "$password"; ?>" name="login" width="1024" height="768" frameborder="0">
```

Comment: can you check what gets submitted to http://myurl.com/verify.php ?

Comment: yeahh i can and as I said it works fine with Firefox and Chrome, the issue is really specific to Internet Explorer 8... cannot find why :S

Comment: It is not very safe to have that password in the open like this.

Answer (score 2):

This may depend on what do you actually pass as username or password. Those values should be [urlencoded](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php). If they're not, some browsers, such as MSIE will (and by principe should) pass the attributes wrong and your code will not work.
Try this:

```
<iframe src="http://myurl.com/verify.php?username=<?php echo urlencode($username); ?>&password=<?php echo urlencode($password); ?>" name="login" width="1024" height="768" frameborder="0">
```

Comment: ok dude thx i will try that in the next min and let you know. Thx cyoher

Comment: No issue remains the same unfortunally, no change at all :(

Comment: Okay, can you post the output of print_r($_POST) in either verify.php and login.php?

Comment: Sure, Array ( [username] => myid [password] => mypwd ) when i fill in "myid" and "mypwd" in the form.

Comment: When I paste this URL in IE8 it works :
http://myurl.com/checklogin.php?username=test&password=mypassword

So I think it's really due to some kind of security stuff from IE8..